# Set a dimension to a plot while keeping the dimension of the output file

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to know how to make the height and width of my plots the same (so that it forms a square) while keeping the size of each page of my pdf file.

```
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)

pl <- lapply(1:20, function(.x) qplot(1:10, rnorm(10),
                                      main=paste("plot", .x))+
               labs(x="", y="", title=""))

lay <- rbind(c(1,2,3),
             c(4,5,6),
             c(7,8,9))

ml <- marrangeGrob(pl, nrow=3, ncol=2,  layout_matrix=lay, left="left",
                   bottom="bottom")

ggsave("file.pdf", ml,  height = 297 , width = 210,
       units = c("mm"),limitsize = FALSE)
```

Comment: Have you considered using an `rmarkdown` document in which you'd run your square plots? If you then exported it to pdf, you'd get an A4 pdf with your square plots embedded. Alternatively, you could resize your small pdf to A4 using an external tool like ghostscript.

Comment: Hello, I had thought about using an external tool to set up the A4 format but I wanted to know if it was possible to do it directly under R.